# Get the name of a Dart class as a Type or String

Tags: dart, flutter

### Problem I need to solve

Is there a way to get the class name of a `dart class` as a `String` or a `Type` object..?

```
class MyClass {
}
var myClass = MyClass();
```

I know the `property`, `runtimeType` which return the type of the object as a `Type` object. But is there a similar function for classes?

```
print(myClass.runtimeType.toString());
```

What I currently do is creating an object of the class and use `runtimeType`.

```
String type = MyClass().runtimeType.toString();
```

Note: In `python` there is a variable called `__name__` in every class, which does what I need.

### My intention

My final goal is to create dart objects using previously saved class names. In [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17766) they have proposed a method using `Map`s. 
The thing is that I have lots of classes and that method looks messy in my situation.

What I currently do is, save the object type by:

```
var saving = myClass.runtimeType.toString();
```

And when loading:

```
if (saving == MyClass().runtimeType.toString()) {
    return MyClass();
}
```

From your experiences and opinions, can you propose a better solution?

Comment: You get an A grade for the clarity and detail of your question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The class type can be used as a `Type`:

```
Type myType = MyClass;
```

Comment: Can I create MyClass instance using myType variable?

Comment: If passing the type as an argument, surrounding the class name with parentheses is sufficient: `(MyClass)`

Answer (score 58):

You can use:

```
var runtimeTypeName = (MyClass).toString();
```

or for generics:

```
var runtimeTypeName = T.toString();
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need to use `(MyClass as Type)`, you can just write `(MyClass).toString()`

Comment: @Ramesh-X Thanks. I tested it and implemented it to the answer since it's simpler.

Comment: Also to avoid calling `.toString()` method you can use interpolation and have it shorter: `'$MyClass'` which will also result with class name.

Comment: Why are the brackets needed?: (MyClass)

Comment: @AjayGautam Without them the compiler will look for a static method of the specific class named `toString`. Parentheses makes casts the specific class' type to `Type` and uses its method.