# How can I print the name of a generic type?

Tags: dart

I have a dart method that takes a generic type.

At the top of the method I want to print the name of the type that was passed as T, is this possible?

eg

```
void myMethod<T> () {
  print("myMethod called with type="+????);
}
```

If myMethod is called with myMethod() it would print "myMethod called with type=String".

Comment: I don't know dart at all, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55835258/get-the-name-of-a-dart-class-as-a-type-or-string it says that you can use `T.toString();`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

You can write

```dart
void myMethod<T> () {
  print("myMethod called with type=$T");
}
```

The only problem is that the Dart libraries don't *promise* that a `Type` object (which is what `T` evaluates to) will have a `toString` which returns the source name of the type in the original program.

It generally does give that string, but if you compile for the web with "minification", it might *not* keep the source names available.

There is also no promise that the `toString` of `Type` won't change in the future, since it is entirely unspecified.